# Unity DoTween Lags the first time i press a button (to scale and rotate an UI gameobject), why?

Tags: unity-game-engine, tween, dotween

the first time I press a button UI (it calls a method that DoTween scale and DoTween rotate the button itself) it lags for half a second.

Just the first time I press it.

Why?

I tried to call `DoTween.Init()` in the main class, before any DoTween.. but it still lag (only the first time I press the button).

Edit:
Probably is a EventSystem initialization thing, how can i solve it?

The first time i press a button.. there is a lag, as shown in the image.
I see that is the "Blue" part (the code) that spikes, and in the details i see that the StandAloneInputModule and the EventSystem are the cause of it.

It happens only on Android, when in the editor does not happen.

What is the solution to remove this horrible lag the first time?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a video and/or some code? It's nearly impossible to guess without any resource.

Comment: I actually used the profiler and i have seen that probably is due to the EventSystem, and not the DoTween library. But how can i solve it? (the frame selected is when the lag spike happens)

Comment: It happens only on Android, when in the editor does not happen.

Comment: Use `Deep Profile` option and hierarchy view instead of the timeline. Then you can see in detail what is going on.